# Is there any way to record sounds from keyboard as midi notes to DAW?

Tags: recording, midi, keyboard

I've got some nice presets on my keyboard and I wonder if recording audio is the only option here? Is this possible to record these sounds as midi notes or is this kind of thing possible only in DAW with instruments vst's.

What I mean is, can I record a performance in my DAW as MIDI data, then edit the MIDI in my DAW, and then play the edited MIDI performance from my DAW through my keyboard?

edit:
I'm using keyboard Casio ct-x5000 and FL studio :)

Comment: If you can edit or comment on what DAW you are using and what make and model your keyboard is, we can give you detailed answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

You seem to already have the first part down: from your question I'm guess you know how to connect your keyboard and record MIDI data into your DAW. You are probably playing that MIDI data back through a virtual instrument instead of through your keyboard.

In most DAWs, there are two different kinds of tracks that have MIDI. The first kind has MIDI and a virtual instrument loaded and might be called an "Instrument Track" (Logic and Pro Tools call it that). The second kind of track is just MIDI data and might be called a "MIDI Track". In Ableton Live, MIDI tracks do both, and it depends on whether you have an instrument device loaded on the MIDI track or not.

In this case, you want to use the MIDI track type, and you don't want to have a virtual instrument loaded into the track. When you hit play on your DAW, no sound should come out (from that track).

Now you have to find the MIDI routing options for your DAW for that track. If you've found it, then you want to choose to route the MIDI output of the track either to the appropriate keyboard that should show up in the list if you have a USB MIDI connection, or the MIDI out of your interface if you are using a regular DIN MIDI cable. In the second case, make sure you have **two** MIDI cables between your keyboard and your MIDI interface.

Now when you hit play, MIDI data should go out through the interface or the USB cable to the keyboard and play the notes on the keyboard. You might also have to adjust the MIDI channels used by the keyboard and the track in the DAW.

Comment: Ok, so the only way to record those cool sounds stored in keyboard is to record audio of them?

Comment: @Raven322 I might have misunderstood your question. Can you look at the edit I made and see if that's what you're asking about?

Comment: Thanks for this edit, I didn't know about that, but I think you answered my question in your first statement. Hah I thought I can record them as midi to my DAW to later edit their lenght etc.

Comment: @Raven322 You can record MIDI to your DAW and then play back the MIDI from your DAW to your keyboard so that the edited MIDI is now playing the cool sounds in your keyboard. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I didn't know it is possible! I'll read manual for more information.

Comment: I am currently connecting my keyboard with my computer with TS jack cable going through  left/mono line output. It goes to my Tascam audio interface and then from tascam to my computer. I guess I can't send midi through jack and I'll have to use USB connection to perform what you wrote about, right?